# jquery value separated by semi-colon

Tags: jquery

The value of `tousers` has users separated by a semi-colon.

```
<input type='text' class='tousers' value='admin;user1;user2;user3;useradmin;' />
```

How do I search if `admin` already exists between semi-colons? So the below code wouldn't add `admin` to `tousers` because it already exists.

```
var content = 'admin';

var to = input.find('.tousers').val();

if(to == "") {
    input.find('.tousers').val(content);
} else {
    input.find('.tousers').val(to + ';' + content);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add the new item to the `tousers` input element if it is already not available, else show an alert saying "Already present"

```
   $(function(){
      var newContent = 'user1';  
      var existingContent=$(".tousers").val()
      var existingArr=existingContent.split(";")
      var isPresent=$.inArray(newContent ,existingArr)       
      if(isPresent<0)
      {       
          $(".tousers").val(existingContent+newContent+";" );
      }
      else      
      {
         alert("Already present");
      }    
    });
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/WsELx/11/

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = 'admin';

var text = jQuery('.rousers').val();

var values = text.split(';')

var contentExists = jQuery.inArray(content, values)
```

Comment: what if `administrator` is in the value instead of `admin`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to test if the string is already in the value:

```
new RegExp("(^|;)" + content + "(;|$)").test(to)
```

(using indexOf is insufficient)

Comment: Haven't tested this out yet but i don't how to use RegExp, do you recommend any tutorials?

Comment: The (^|;) matches either the start of the string or a semicolon, and, similarly, the (;|$) matches either the end of the string or a semicolon.

Comment: This was the site I originally used to learn regular expressions:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: For their use in Javascript in particular, check out this page:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: `if (! new RegExp("(^|;)" + content + "(;|$)").test(to)) input.find('.tousers').val(to+';'+content);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(/\badmin\b/.test('admin;user1;user2;user3;useradmin;')) // has admin inside your string
```

Or in your case

```
if(/\badmin\b/.test(to))
```

The regex `\badmin\b` searches, in a string - for an admin bounded by 2 word boundaries

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$.inArray(value, array)`

```
var content = 'admin';
var to = $('.tousers').val();
var array = to.split(';');

if ($.inArray(content, array) == -1){
   $('.tousers').val(to + ';' + content); 
}
```